# Eighties novel about robot killers who look like kids assassinating various military leaders, politicians and scientists

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was a hardback book from a UK library – I read it in the late eighties. No memories of the book cover.
Some may say this is just a ‘techno thriller’ but there was a strong robot element.

What I remember, evil organisation (or Cold War enemy) with bad scientists is having a go at world domination. They begin by assassinating various military leaders, politicians and scientists.

One weapon deployed are robots that look like cute little kids (This is NOT "Second Variety" by PKD) and these robots approach their targets at home, pleading for help. Once they're at close range they explode and kill the leaders and anyone else within several yards.

There is a frantic race on between the good defender teams and the evil killer teams, one side trying to stop the killer robots and the other side trying to carry out the hits.

One bit I recall is a couple of kid robots have strolled into a chocolate shop and are acting enthusiastic for white chocolate. This was to gain the owners trust so they could get a scientist's address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the 1986 novel [*Brothers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothers_(Goldman_novel)) by William Goldman.

***What I remember, evil organisation (or Cold War enemy) with bad scientists is having a go at world domination.***

> The plot concerns an effort to instigate World War III by means of simultaneous, worldwide terrorist attacks, which Scylla attempts to stop.

***They begin by assassinating various military leaders, politicians and scientists.***

> Scylla's job is to kill American scientists who made three inventions meant to give the United States a military advantage against the Soviet Union. There are two factions in the U.S. government, the Bloodies, advocating war, and Godists, who wish for more peaceful methods.

***One weapon deployed are robots that look like cute little kids (This is NOT "Second Variety" by PKD) and these robots approach their targets at home, pleading for help. Once they're at close range they explode and kill the leaders and anyone else within several yards.***

> The final invention is exploding children made to kill important politicians and scientists to goad major world powers into attacking each other so the United Kingdom, left standing, could rule the world.

***There is a frantic race on between the good defender teams and the evil killer teams, one side trying to stop the killer robots and the other side trying to carry out the hits.***

> Scylla initially recovers on an island, as he had been in recovery for a decade. He later goes to New York State, both New York City and Upstate New York. At Princeton University he kills "Arky" Vaughan, who made the suicide chemical, while in New York he kills Milo Standish, who created a chemical that makes other people do his wishes.

IMHO, a terrible attempt by Goldman to write sf and a disappointing sequel to *Marathon Man*.

Comment: That's the one, cheers. Once you named the author I remembered  - it was a bit poor but the faint memory of exploding kids was annoying me.

Comment: I also think I remember the chocolate shop scene but I no longer have a copy to confirm it.